# Spark cluster set up error

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

With some research over the internet, I can use

```
sbin/start-master.sh
```

to start the spark master server spark service over my Ubuntu Linux computers
and use

```
bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://...
```

for the slave nodes service up and running.
The good news was I can see the local web page with works found alive.

However, after such, I tried to launch the shell to work ...

```
MASTER=spark://localhost:7077 bin/spark-shell
```

but it returned:
sparkMaster@localhost:7077 ...

And therefore I modified the code to

```
MASTER=spark://sparkuser@localhost:7077 bin/spark-shell
```

where the sparkuser is the one connected to the two nodes
However, with such modification, I got:

```
ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

and when I tried

```
MASTER=local-cluster[3,2,1024] bin/spark-shell
```

It did come out with the spark logo in the shell but I was afraid the slave nodes were not binding in.

Did I miss anything for the Spark cluster setting?

Answer (score 0):

Just launch spark-shell on cluster with --master flag as follows

```
       ./spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077 bin/spark-shell
```